# Wordpress causing all code to be displayed on line 1. Receiving multiple errors after cleaning cookies and cache

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have been working on a wordpress theme for a few days and when I realized my JS file for my theme customizer wasn't updating I decided to clear the cookies and cache, and wow that was problematic. As soon as I did that I recieved this error many times, mainly stating the file I am working on(customize.php and the other file it said was pluggable.php:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by customize.php
```

After I tried to login I am now receiving this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION on line 1
```

Everytime I replace the file with a previous version it keeps messing up the format of the code and making it all one line of code as soon as I refresh the page and redownload the file.

I don't understand what is causing this. Why is it making the whole file 1 line? It makes it harder for me to find the original issue.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97520/wordpress-causing-all-code-to-be-displayed-on-line-1-receiving-multiple-errors

Comment: Yes I posted that first, then I realized the issue was most likely more a php issue instead of a wp issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know without more specifics, but it sounds like you may be missing a `<?php` or `?>` somewhere, which could cause the browser to simply print out all your PHP code. If you did any tinkering recently, make sure you didn't remove either of those, or a missing `;` at the end of any lines.

If everything is correct, you might also try turning of WP's error reporting. I've had "headers already sent errors" with certain themes when the `wp_debug` is set to true.